# Problema código ASCII en windows 10 / C++

Tags: c++, ascii

Soy nuevo en esto del mundo de la programación y ahora mismo me encuentro realizando un programa del Black Jack en C++. Resulta que a la hora de imprimir los símbolos de los palos de las cartas (corazón, tréboles etc...) no me funcionan. Lo hago con el código ascii, para el corazón por ejemplo es `char(03)`.

Tengo duda de por qué en Windows 10 no me deja, mientras que en Windows 7 sí. ¿Hay alguna manera de poder mostrar los símbolos en la consola en Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

El motivo es que Windows 10 está utilizando una codificación diferente. Por ejemplo un sistema podría estar usando UTF-8 y el otro unicode.

Los caracteres no son más que números. Estos números son índices que se han de localizar en una tabla de caracteres para encontrar el caracter a imprimir.

Por otro lado tenemos que los caracteres que dices que estás usando no forman parte de la [tabla ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), que es la única parte portable entre diferentes tablas de caracteres.

Así pues ahí tienes el problema. Un Sistema Operativo (Windows 7) está usando una tabla de caracteres compatible con la codificación de tu archivo de código fuente mientras que el otro (Windows 10) usa una tabla diferente y eso hace que los caracteres impresos sean diferentes.

La solución pasa por configurar la consola para que use la tabla de caracteres que a tí te interesa. Para este menester puedes consultar el siguiente [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-code-pages)